# Is there a LINQ way of converting a generic list of objects to an X by Y matrix of the same type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, generics

I have a generic list of objects, for example: `List<Photo>` and want to convert this to something I can use on an MVC view.

In the form (basic example):

```
<% foreach (var row in PhotoList) { %>

// Render Matrix (using photo properties)
<tr>
    <% foreach(photo in row) { %>
    <td><%=photo.Name%></td>
    <% } %>
</tr>

<% } %>
```

I have thought of doing this manually, using something like `List<List<Photo>>()`, but is there a nifty way of doing this using [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query)? Supplying the number of columns, rows and page a paged Matrix Display, or other better ideas.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement and wonder how you would get `List<List<Photo>>` from `List<Photo>`? A List is a single dimensional array, not 2D which is what a Matrix is.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand either, but I wonder if this is what you want: http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Batch.cs. But since you're using a `List<T>`, ye ole pal, the for loop would work just as well, or even better.

Comment: I *suspect* what he might be wanting is to somehow use this to handle the rows of a table; that the data structure being returned has, for example, four items in each row max, so he can iterate through the "rows" of items. If I am right, though, I think that needlessly complicates things - it's much easier to simply handle the rows within the view as it's being built, IMO.

Comment: @Andrew Barber: Yes, something like that, just updated the question again, with a better usage example. But the real question is getting the MatrixList from a basic List.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a matrix using `GroupBy()` given the number of columns `x` you want:

```
photos.Select( (photo, index) => new { Index = index, Photo = photo })
      .GroupBy( n=> n.Index / x)
      .Select( g => g.Select( p=> p.Photo).ToList())
      .ToList();
```

The result is a `List<List<Photo>>` with `x` photos in each inner list. You should then just be able to use two foreach loops to render them (as in your example).

Comment: This is what I was after, need to learn more of this, thanks!